# Fill a multi-dimentional array with values from another array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I need to write a method that will return a multi-dimentional array composed of elements from a given array, each row should have numbers with corresponding number of digits, for example first row should have numbers with one digit, second row numbers with two digits, third row number with 3 digits.

I managed to sort the given array. I included part of my miserable attempt to calculate how many digits a number has. Can't get my head around what to do next.

Appreciate any help.

```
class test {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        int arr[] = {20,11,100,9,3,200,4000};
        method(arr);
    }

    public static int[][] method(int arr[]){
        int arr1[][] = new int[50][50];
        for(int j=0;j<arr.length-1;j++){
            int minIndex = j;
            for(int i=j+1;i<arr.length;i++){
                if(arr[minIndex]>arr[i]){
                    minIndex = i;
                }
            }
            int temp = arr[minIndex];
            arr[minIndex] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = temp;
        }

        int k =0;
        while(k<arr.length) {
            int counter = 0;

            while (arr[k] != 0) {
                arr[k] /= 10;
                counter++;
            }
            k++;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did your course cover creating methods? If yes then consider creating one like `int getAmountOfDigits(int x){...}` so you would avoid nesting your code (readability helps to solve problems faster).

Comment: Assume, for the moment, that you've solved the issue of finding how many digits a number has.  You've got your sorted 1d array.  You've got your empty 2d array ready and waiting.  Do you know, or at least have a good guess, about what the next step is?

Comment: Are arrays a constraint? that would be lot easier with Lists

Answer (score 0):

This could be done lot more easily using List as it is not straightforward to add an element to an array.
Read the comments in the code below to see how it works

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    int arr[] = {20,11,100,9,3,200,4000};

    int[][] sortedArray = new int[50][]; // fixing the size to 50 so we can go up to 50 digits, that could also be dynamic but it would make the code heavier
    int nbDigits;
    int[] tmpArray;
    for(int i : arr) {
        // get the number of digits
        nbDigits = nbDigits(i);

        // retrieve the array to add the integer to
        tmpArray = sortedArray[nbDigits-1];

        // add the integer to the array
        tmpArray = addToArray(tmpArray, i);

        // stick back your array in the multidimensional array
        sortedArray[nbDigits-1] = tmpArray;
    }
}
```

This method adds an element to a given array.

```
private static int[] addToArray(int[] array, int n) {
    int[] returnArray;
    if(array == null) {
        returnArray = new int[1];
        returnArray[0] = n;
    } else {
        // copy the array in an other array 1 bigger
        returnArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length + 1);
        // add your number at the end
        returnArray[array.length] = n;
    }
    return returnArray;
}
```

This method calculates the number of digits of an integer by making it a string and returning it length

```
private static int nbDigits(int n) {
    return String.valueOf(n).length();
}
```